# Efficiently store and evaluate a large number of boolean expressions

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures, boolean, scalability

I have a huge set (20000) of boolean expressions. They consist of `AND`, `OR` and `NOT` operators and a large number of boolean variables `A1`, `A2`, `A3` ... (about 1000). Most expression contain only 5, maybe 20 of these variables.

Given an assignment of the variables (`A1 = true, A2 = false, A3 = false ...`) I have to find those expressions that evaluate to `false`.

The same set of expressions will be evaluated for multiple (10-100) assignments

For this purpose:

1. How should I store the expressions on disk so I can load and parse them fast (I currently have them either as some specialized DSL or as a more or less normalized (and dead slow) relational data structure, but I can change that)
2. Is there a fast algorithm / data structure for evaluating such expressions that I can use?
3. Do implementations on the JVM exist?

Comment: Will you be evaluating a particular expression many times or just once?

Comment: Have you looked at [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/)?

As for algorithms ... have a look at sparse bitsets (the java.util.Bitset class is not sparse, but is very fast and may be ok for the relatively small numbers you're dealing with).

Comment: Take a look at Binary Decision Diagrams (BDDs). They were specifically designed to simplify and validate the boolean logic of integrated circuits.

Comment: @ChrisGerken I updated the question: The same set of expressions will be evaluated for multiple (10-100) assignments

Comment: @JensSchauder: That still isn't a lot, unless you have ridiculous time constraints. A naive solution should be able to do 10-100 iterations in a second or 2 unless your equations are long, which by the looks of the number of variables they aren't.

Comment: @wildplasser Looks like a usefull structure, but how do I build a good one. wikipedia says that is NP hard and 'there exist efficient heuristics' but no hint what those are.

Comment: It is *only* the ordering that is NP-complete. Most "random" problems will be reasonable well-formed; only a few will be evil. I expaect that your "multi rooted" problem will be from the nice kind of the family. The Bryant paper is a good introduction and a must-read.

Comment: Thanx everybody. Most helpfull where Petes & RBarryYoungs and wildplassers comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SOP answer to this is to store the expressions as strings in RPN (Reverse Polish Notation) and then write a simple Stack Machine parser to evaluate them.

Generally, an RPN string can be evaluated almost as fast as an already in-memory AST (Abstract Symbol Tree).  And the stack machine parser is dead easy to write.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to look at converting your expressions into [Conjunctive Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) and combining like terms. You then can have a two-way mapping of an expression to a set of terms, any of which evaluating to false implies that the whole expression evaluates false. For each assignment of variables, start with a set of expressions, evaluate CNF terms until one evaluates to false. If that term is false, then all expressions involving that term will also be false, so those expressions can also be removed from the set.

Whether such an approach fits your case can't be said without looking at the expressions - with 1000 variables and 20000 expressions, it might not be that they have many CNF terms in common.

Outside of Java, and for much larger numbers of expressions, DNF is possibly more useful, since its implementation on the GPU is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You seem attached to Java, but have you considered feeding these things to a language that has an eval() function?  It would probably reduce the problem to saving an expression in a file and evaluating it.  Note that if you don't trust the (source of the) expressions, this has security implications!

Jython comes to mind, but there are probably several that would make very short work of this.

If you're married to java, you could probably implement a recursive descent parser for boolean algebra.  But that's quite a bit more involved.

Comment: I'm somewhat attached to Java and even more to the JVM since anything else will cause knowhow and deployment problems over here. I'm not afraid of implementing a parseras long as the result is fast.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: The following site has [code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Truth_table) that might help.

Convert your list of expressions into source code for a function that when called with the value of the variables will evaluate all the functions and return an indication of which expressions evaluate to false. compile the function then call it for your different variable values.

I have done similar and used Python. The only parsing and interpretation I had to write was to translate the input boolean operators, '&', '|', '~' into their Python equivalents.

Your problem size seems quite OK for a Python solution.

Comment: Regarding the link: a truth table for 1000 input parameters doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Comment: This problem isn't about generating truth tables. The link has code for representing and evaluating boolean expressions. Sometimes you need to extract what you need as the full answer isn't handed to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could build an index where for each variable you record two sets of expressions, those where the variable occurs positively and those where it occurs negatively. Depending on the values of the variables you collect those expressions which could become false due to this variable (positive occurrences if the variables is set to false and vice versa). **Edit:** These are just candidates, you still need to evaluate them to find out if they really become false.

Whether this helps compared to just evaluating all your expressions depends on the structure of your expressions and how many evaluate to false.

Comment: Would the expression `(a&b)|(!a&c)` be in the positive or negative set for `a`? Given a set of values for a,b,c, how would you collect the corresponding expressions without having to evaluate them completely?

Comment: @Pete Kirkham The expression would be in both, since `a` occurs both positively and negatively. A positive occurrence is where there is an even number of negations on the path to the root of the expression, a negative where there is an odd number.

Comment: So how would being in both lead to determining whether the expression is true or false if a is false?

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert them into CNF and use MiniSat to check whether the expression evaluates to true or false